# Why there are stray pixels in computing the average of grayscale images?

Tags: python, image, opencv, grayscale

I am computing the average of three grayscale images attached herewith.
image1Each image is of size 256 x 256. Upon averaging, I am getting several stray pixels in the averaged output. Given below is the code I am using to generate the averaged image.
[image: image1] [image: image2]

[image: image3] [image: avg_output]

[image: avg_without_255_multiplication]

```
import cv2
img1 = 'image1.png'
img2 = 'image2.png'
img3 = 'image3.png'

img_1 = cv2.imread(img1).astype("float32")
img_2 = cv2.imread(img2).astype("float32")
img_3 = cv2.imread(img3).astype("float32")

# averaging
result = 255*((img_1 + img_2 + img_3)/3)
result1 = result.clip(0, 255).astype("uint8")    
cv2.imwrite('avg.png', result1)
```

Comment: You are only dividing ima_3 by 3.  `result = 255*((img_1 + img_2 + img_3/3))` should be `result = 255*((img_1 + img_2 + img_3)/3). You have a misplaced parenthesis on the right side. Division is done before addition.

Comment: @fmw42: That's great! But it didn't resolve the problem. Find included the new averaged image that still contains stray pixels.

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 255? Wouldn't the input and output images have the same numeric range?

Comment: Your images have dark values at (1,1,1). The image are not fully black everywhere that looks black. So when you average and multiply by 255, which is wrong as said in the other comment by Jifi Baum, you amplify those 1s to 255s. OpenCV clamps values outside the range 0 to 255. So you get those extra white regions.  You should simply do `result = ((img_1 + img_2 + img_3)/3)`. Just because you convert to float does not mean it is automatically in the range 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jifi has the answer.  If you had printed the arrays you're reading, you would have realized that those arrays ALREADY run from 0 to 255.  You assumed they run from 0 to 1.  If you remove the `255*`, you'll get the results you expect.

That does say that at least some of your images do have stray pixels down in that bottom area.  A pixel value of 1 (out of 255) in any of the images would result in 85 in the final average.

### Followup

OK, I'm now assuming that what you really want is the UNION of those three images, not the AVERAGE.  If so, this will do it:

```
import cv2
img1 = 'x1.png'
img2 = 'x2.png'
img3 = 'x3.png'

img_1 = cv2.imread(img1) > 1
img_2 = cv2.imread(img2) > 1
img_3 = cv2.imread(img3) > 1

result = ((img_1 | img_2 | img_3) * 255).astype("uint8")
cv2.imwrite('avg.png', result)
```

So, `img_x` will contain True where the image pixel value is larger than 1.  True and False behave as 1 and 0 in arithmetic computations.

If you change the `> 1` to `> 0`, you will see all of the non-zero pixels in your original images, which gives you the stray blobs at the bottom.

Comment: I am very sure none of my images have stray pixels down in the bottom area as you mentioned. You can see the images with adequate spaces  between them in the edited question. Also removing the '255 *' is resulting in a strange image as shown in the bottom-most row but this time it didn't contain any stray pixels.

Comment: The bottom image is exactly correct.  The areas of the blob that only appear in one image will be 1/3 intensity.  The areas that only appear in two images will be 2/3 intensity.  And since you gave us the three images, I can tell you for certain that all three of them contain pixels values between 1 and 254.  #1 has 357, #2 has 1254, #3 has 828.  Those are what produced your smudges.

Comment: Perhaps what you really want is to treat this as monochrome (0 and 1) instead of grayscale.  Could that be it?

Comment: Yes, I would like to convert them to binary and have only 0 and 1 pixels. What values should I use to perform otsu thresholding of the bottom image?